# Не работают одновременно масштабирование и перемещение в яндекс картах апи

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, яндекс-карты

```
 $('#maps_msk').click(
function(){myMap.panTo([55.753559, 37.609218], {flying: 1},{callback: function () { myMap.setZoom(11, { smooth: true });}} )});
```

Ребят, подскажите. Может в коде где-то ошибка?

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Проблема в том, что код рабочий, а масштабирование не происходит. Только перемещение. Однако, если оставить только setZoom, то масштабирование работает.

Answer (score 1):

Зум работает только если они не превышает значение в 10. Почему не знаю.